# Setting the path of a file that is to be created

Tags: java, path, text-editor

I am currently working on a Text Editor in Java. Here is the code so far:

```
package com.thundercrust.applications;

public class TextEditor implements ActionListener{

private static Formatter format = new Formatter();

private static String[] fontOptions = {"Serif", "Agency FB", "Arial", "Calibri", "Cambrian", "Century Gothic", "Comic Sans MS", "Courier New", "Forte", "Garamond", "Monospaced", "Segoe UI", "Times New Roman", "Trebuchet MS", "Serif"};
private static String[] sizeOptions = {"8", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28", "30", "32", "34", "36", "38", "40"};

ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("res/NewIcon.png");
ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("res/SaveIcon.png");
ImageIcon openIcon = new ImageIcon("res/OpenIcon.png");
ImageIcon fontIcon = new ImageIcon("res/FontIcon.png");
ImageIcon changeFontIcon = new ImageIcon("res/ChangeFontIcon.png");

JButton New = new JButton(newIcon);
JButton Save = new JButton(saveIcon);
JButton Open = new JButton(openIcon);
JButton changeFont = new JButton(changeFontIcon);

JLabel fontLabel = new JLabel(fontIcon);
JLabel fontLabelText = new JLabel("Font: ");
JLabel fontSizeLabel = new JLabel("Size: ");

JComboBox <String> fontName = new JComboBox<>(fontOptions);
JComboBox <String> fontSize = new JComboBox<>(sizeOptions);

JToolBar tool = new JToolBar();

JTextArea texty = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(texty);

private static final int WIDTH = 1366;
private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;

private static String name = "Text Editor"; 

private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public void Display() {
    frame.setTitle(name);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    New.addActionListener(this);
    New.setToolTipText("Creates a new File");
    Save.addActionListener(this);
    Save.setToolTipText("Saves the current File");
    Open.addActionListener(this);
    Open.setToolTipText("Opens a file");
    changeFont.addActionListener(this);
    changeFont.setToolTipText("Change the Font");

    fontLabel.setToolTipText("Font");

    fontLabelText.setToolTipText("Set the kind of Font");
    fontSizeLabel.setToolTipText("Set the size of the Font");

    tool.add(New);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(Save);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(Open);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(fontLabel);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(fontLabelText);
    tool.add(fontName);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(fontSizeLabel);
    tool.add(fontSize);
    tool.addSeparator();
    tool.add(changeFont);

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(tool, "North");
    pane.add(scroll, "Center");
    frame.setContentPane(pane);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TextEditor editor = new TextEditor();
    editor.Display();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String fontNameSet;
    String fontSizeSetTemp;
    int fontSizeSet;
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if(source == New) {
        texty.setText("");
    }
    else if(source == changeFont) {
        fontNameSet = (String) fontName.getSelectedItem();
        fontSizeSetTemp = (String) fontSize.getSelectedItem();
        fontSizeSet = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeSetTemp);
        texty.setFont(new Font(fontNameSet,  Font.PLAIN, fontSizeSet));
    }
    else if(source == Save) {
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file: "); 
        System.out.println(fileName);

        String path = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the path of the file: ");
        System.out.println(path);

        try {
            format = new Formatter(fileName + ".txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        format.format(texty.getText());

        format.close();
    }

}
}
```

As you can see, I've implemented a path system.

However, I cant set the path of the file to the path that the user inputs.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please isolate the code to show where the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable the user to choose which path to save his text file, I think you should use `jFileChooser` (Swing) or `Jfiledialog` (AWT).

Example of using `jFileChooser`:

```
//file f;  
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
     fc.showSaveDialog(this);
      f=fc.getSelectedFile();
      if(f!=null)
    {
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
            System.out.println(jTextArea1.getText());
            pw.print(jTextArea1.getText());
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
}
```